# Long relative download time of first downloaded javascript file in Chrome DevTools

Tags: web-development, performance

I'm testing the performance of a website using the network tab of Chrome DevTools. When I open the web page in a fresh incognito window, I noticed that the first downloaded javascript, which is jquery.min.js, usually takes much longer to download that any other subsequent script of similar size.

[image: screenshot]

I would like to know if this is a normal behavior or if it is something that can be fixed, or maybe I'm not interpreting correctly the waterfall?

Comment: Is it being downloaded from your own domain or is it from a public CDN?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller From my own domain and server (a VPS).